# Find all five digit number $\overline{abcde}$ such that $\overline{abcde} = \overline{(ace})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all five digit number $\overline{abcde}$ such that $$\overline{abcde} = \overline{(ace})^2$$

This question popped in my mind while solving other elementary numbers and I have been trying to solve it ever since but without any luck.

**My Take :** Since the digit place of $e^2$ should be equal to digit's place of $e$ , So the only possible values of $e$ are $0,1,5$ and $6$

Also since the First digit of the numbers are equal , We can conclude that the the only possible values of $a=1$.

Hence our number can take the following form :

$$(1bcd0),(1bcd1),(1bcd5),(1bcd6)$$

**But how do we further solve this?**

Also Another interesting part of this question would be to solve for $\overline{abcd}$ such that $$\overline{abcd} = \overline{(bd)}^2$$

Comment: Given that $a=1$, at worst you have to search the numbers from $100$ to $199$.  Quite a lot fewer as the last digit is also constrained.

Comment: You are right , but are there any more logical or mathematical ways to reduce the possibilities further?

Comment: There only seem to be three cases.  For example you can exclude anything above $100\sqrt{2}$

Comment: in fact lulu using PARI/GP you can show there are only 5 numbers in the whole of the three digit range, that have squares that leave 2 other digits to be $b$ and $d$ in any order.

Comment: As others have remarked, the search is really extremely narrow.  This sort of problem often comes down to some case work.

Comment: Furthermore you can note that $a+b+c+d+e$ cannot be $2 \pmod 3$, or $3 \pmod 4$, or $2, 3 \pmod 5$ and so on.

Comment: I think all answers are $\sqrt{10000}=100$, $\sqrt{11025}=105$, $\sqrt{11025}=105$.  If you don't require $\overline{abcde}$ to have $5$ digits (i.e., $a=0$ is possible, $a=b=0$ is possible, etc), then I think all the solutions with $a=0$ are $\sqrt{00000}=000$, $\sqrt{00001}=001$, $\sqrt{00025}=005$, $\sqrt{00036}=006$, $\sqrt{00100}=010$, $\sqrt{00121}=11$, $\sqrt{02500}=050$, $\sqrt{03600}=060$, $\sqrt{05776}=076$.

Comment: @WE!  Shhhhh!  You blew my cover!

Comment: Anyway, I meant to say $\sqrt{10000}$, $\sqrt{11025}=105$, and $\sqrt{12100}=110$ (not sure why I repeated $105$, instead of $110$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can minimize trial and error with some clever use of modular arithmetic.

Let $N=100a+10c+e$ be the square root.  Thus $N^2\equiv e^2$ and we require also $N^2\equiv e\bmod 10$.  Therefore $e^2\equiv e$ forcing $e\in\{0,1,5,6\}$.

We also know that $(100a)^2<10000(a+1)$ or $a^2<a+1$ forcing $a=1$.  Then $N^2<20000$ but $145^2>140×150=21000$, therefore $N<145$.  This result together with the earlier constraint on $e$ leaves only eighteen candidates, which can be exhaustively searched with little trouble; but we can do even better than that.

Consider the case $e=0$.  Then $N=100+10c$ (with $a=1$) and $N^2=10000+2000c+100c^2$.  For the hundreds digit in $N^2$ to match $c$ we must then have $c^2\equiv c\bmod 10$.  This constraint admits$c\in\{0,1,5,6\}$, but only $0$ and $1$ satisfy the bounty $N<145$ which implies $c\le 4$.  Thereby we identify

$100^2=10000$

$110^2=12100$

For $e=1$ we have

$N^2=10000+2000c+100(c^2+2)+20c+1$

With $c\le 4$, $20c+1<100$ and thus the hundreds digit is $\equiv c^2+2\bmod 10$.  Therefore we must satisfy

$c^2-c+2\equiv 0\bmod 10$

which has a discriminant that is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 5$.  So nobody's home here.

The cases $e=5$ and $e=6$ are left to the reader; they are handled similarly to $e=1$ as described above.  For these cases $N<145$ implies $c\le 3$ which will then fix the hundreds digit of $N^2$ as $\equiv c^2+c$ ($e=5$) or $\equiv c^2+c+2$ ($e=6$).  We will then get only one additional solution which the reader can find.  I list the complete solution set as (with $x$ digits to be filled in):

$100^2=10000$

$1xx^2=1xxxx$

$110^2=12100$